# Failed to free up 208019456 on /data; final free space 141062144:

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I am getting the following error while running an android app in Android Studio 3.2

> 2018-10-25 00:47:41.743 1709-1709/? E/installd: Failed to free up 208019456 on /data; final free space 141062144: Success
>   2018-10-25 00:47:41.744 1839-1946/? W/DeviceStorageMonitorService: java.io.IOException: Failed to free 208019456 on storage device at /data
>           at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.freeStorage(PackageManagerService.java:4656)
>           at com.android.server.storage.DeviceStorageMonitorService.check(DeviceStorageMonitorService.java:194)
>           at com.android.server.storage.DeviceStorageMonitorService.access$100(DeviceStorageMonitorService.java:73)
>           at com.android.server.storage.DeviceStorageMonitorService$1.handleMessage(DeviceStorageMonitorService.java:258)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to find the solution myself and found that the Android Emulator was not able to delete the "temporary data" from the device after closing the app. 
To solve this issue:
I had to delete the content of /data folder from the android emulator.

Basically, some apps create temporary data in the device. If the App fails to delete those files on exit, due to crash or some other reason, they start accumulating and take up space in memory, this results in the error: "W/DeviceStorageMonitorService: java.io.IOException: Failed to free 208019456 on storage device at /data"

Answer (score 1):

I solve this issue by:
Open AVD Manager Then on My Android Emulator choose Wipe Data from option.

[image]